How to separate elements of a list based on a delimiter that not all elements contain?
I have performed an analysis (explained below for background) that produced a table with a list of gene names as the row names. Some of these gene names have an additional suffix added, ".#", e.g. .1, .2, etc.
Here is a slice of the rownames from the middle of the table. You can see that most have a ".#" suffix, but some do not.
 "Cck", "Pcp4.3", "Adcy1.4", "Cpe.3", "Dsp.5", "Dgkh.4", "Ncdn.4", "Marcksl1.3","Fam163b.5","Stxbp6.3","Prox1.3", "Neurod6.3", "Dock10.2","Fth1.3","Ipcef1","Pgbd5.3","Sema5a.2","Ahcyl2.2","Hpca.3","Gpr151"

These suffixes shouldn't be there. My first guess to remove them was using a dplyr solution like
df %>% rownames_to_column(var = "Gene.ID") %>% separate_wider_delim(Gene.ID, delim = ".", names = c("Gene", "num")) 

but that approach returned this error:
Error in `separate_wider_delim()`:
! Expected 2 pieces in each element of `Gene.ID`.
! 3271 values were too short.
ℹ Use `too_few = "debug"` to diagnose the problem.
ℹ Use `too_few = "align_start"/"align_end"` to silence this message.
! 2 values were too long.
ℹ Use `too_many = "debug"` to diagnose the problem.
ℹ Use `too_many = "drop"/"merge"` to silence this message.
Backtrace:
 1. All_Markers %>% rownames_to_column(var = "Gene.ID") %>% ...
 2. tidyr::separate_wider_delim(., Gene.ID, delim = ".", names = c("Gene", "Occur"))

I think that this is happening because some elements do not contain the delimiter. Is there any way to get around this?
Extra Background:
The software is running the analysis on numerous comparisons in the same batch and inputting the resultant gene names as rownames. I assume, that since rownames must be unique, a suffix is added to avoid repetition. Because of this, I anticipate that the numerical suffix = (# of occurrences) - 1
But I would like to be sure of this, I want to separate the genes by the delimiter and make a frequency table of each gene name and compare it with the pulled suffixes to confirm.

the error message already tells you what to do. Use too_few and too_,amy arguments I usually set them to "align_start" and "merge". https://tidyr.tidyverse.org/reference/separate_wider_delim.html

You might try
df = data.frame(row.names = x <- c("Cck", "Pcp4.3", "Adcy1.4", "Cpe.3", "Dsp.5", "Dgkh.4", "Ncdn.4", 
                                   "Marcksl1.3","Fam163b.5","Stxbp6.3","Prox1.3", "Neurod6.3", "Dock10.2",
                                   "Fth1.3","Ipcef1","Pgbd5.3","Sema5a.2","Ahcyl2.2","Hpca.3","Gpr151"))
csplit = \(x) {
  x = strsplit(x, split = ".", fixed = TRUE)
  lapply(x, `length<-`, max(lengths(x))) |> do.call(what = rbind)
}
df = cbind.data.frame(csplit(row.names(df))) |>
  `colnames<-`(c("gene", "num")) # cosmetics

gives
> df
       gene  num
1       Cck <NA>
2      Pcp4    3
3     Adcy1    4
4       Cpe    3
5       Dsp    5
6      Dgkh    4
7      Ncdn    4
8  Marcksl1    3
9   Fam163b    5
10   Stxbp6    3
11    Prox1    3
12  Neurod6    3
13   Dock10    2
14     Fth1    3
15   Ipcef1 <NA>
16    Pgbd5    3
17   Sema5a    2
18   Ahcyl2    2
19     Hpca    3
20   Gpr151 <NA>

If this is just a sample of your real data, we probably need to filter the maximum value (num) for each (unique) gene, i.e.: ~ aggregate(num ~ gene, rbind(df, c("Cpe", 4)), max, na.rm = TRUE), as "Cpe" is twice in the data now.

You could match the part of the string you want and replace the entire string with the matched text:
df %>% rownames_to_column(var = "Gene.ID") %>% mutate(Gene.ID = gsub("(.+?)\\..*$", "\\1", Gene.ID))


Here is another way with sub twice.

Create results vectors for the strings/genes and the numbers;
find where there are "." characters with grepl;
delete everything from the dots onward get the genes;
and up to, including, the dots to get the numbers;
return the results as a named list.

The returned list can be coerced to data.frame.
fun <- function(x) {
  left <- right <- rep(NA, length(x))
  i <- grepl("\\.", x)
  left[!i] <- x[!i]
  left[i] <- sub("(^.*)\\..*", "\\1", x[i])
  right[i] <- sub("(^.*)\\.(.*$)", "\\2", x[i])
  list(Gene = left, num = right)
}
res <- fun(x) |> as.data.frame()
head(res)
#>    Gene  num
#> 1   Cck <NA>
#> 2  Pcp4    3
#> 3 Adcy1    4
#> 4   Cpe    3
#> 5   Dsp    5
#> 6  Dgkh    4

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Data
x <- c("Cck", "Pcp4.3", "Adcy1.4", "Cpe.3", "Dsp.5", "Dgkh.4", "Ncdn.4", "Marcksl1.3","Fam163b.5","Stxbp6.3","Prox1.3", "Neurod6.3", "Dock10.2","Fth1.3","Ipcef1","Pgbd5.3","Sema5a.2","Ahcyl2.2","Hpca.3","Gpr151")
x <- scan(text = x, what = "character")

Created on 2024-05-02 with reprex v2.1.0

Using the argument too_few = "align_start" in your current call would give you what you need in almost all cases:
library(tidyverse)

df <- tibble(
  column_in = c(
    "Cck",
    "Pcp4.3",
    "Adcy1.4",
    "Cpe.3",
    "Dsp.5",
    "Dgkh.4",
    "Ncdn.4",
    "Marcksl1.3",
    "Fam163b.5",
    "Stxbp6.3",
    "Prox1.3",
    "Neurod6.3",
    "Dock10.2",
    "Fth1.3",
    "Ipcef1",
    "Pgbd5.3",
    "Sema5a.2",
    "Ahcyl2.2",
    "Hpca.3",
    "Gpr151"
  )
) 

df |>
  separate_wider_delim(
    column_in,
    delim = ".",
    names = c("Gene", "num"),
    too_few = "align_start"
  )
#> # A tibble: 20 × 2
#>    Gene     num  
#>    <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 Cck      <NA> 
#>  2 Pcp4     3    
#>  3 Adcy1    4    
#>  4 Cpe      3    
#>  5 Dsp      5    
#>  6 Dgkh     4    
#>  7 Ncdn     4    
#>  8 Marcksl1 3    
#>  9 Fam163b  5    
#> 10 Stxbp6   3    
#> 11 Prox1    3    
#> 12 Neurod6  3    
#> 13 Dock10   2    
#> 14 Fth1     3    
#> 15 Ipcef1   <NA> 
#> 16 Pgbd5    3    
#> 17 Sema5a   2    
#> 18 Ahcyl2   2    
#> 19 Hpca     3    
#> 20 Gpr151   <NA>

This however is failing in at least two of the rows of your actual data which contain multiple "."s (see your error message). You can use the too_many argument to handle this if you know what it's doing (is it adding a redundant extra ".#" on in some cases? Or is the "." part of the gene name?).
An alternative would be to extract the parts of the string you need, specifying which parts exactly are denoting name vs number:
df |>
  transmute(col1 = str_extract(column_in, "^\\w*"),
            col2 = str_extract(column_in, "(?<=\\.)\\d*$"))
#> # A tibble: 20 × 2
#>    col1     col2 
#>    <chr>    <chr>
#>  1 Cck      <NA> 
#>  2 Pcp4     3    
#>  3 Adcy1    4    
#>  4 Cpe      3    
#>  5 Dsp      5    
#>  6 Dgkh     4    
#>  7 Ncdn     4    
#>  8 Marcksl1 3    
#>  9 Fam163b  5    
#> 10 Stxbp6   3    
#> 11 Prox1    3    
#> 12 Neurod6  3    
#> 13 Dock10   2    
#> 14 Fth1     3    
#> 15 Ipcef1   <NA> 
#> 16 Pgbd5    3    
#> 17 Sema5a   2    
#> 18 Ahcyl2   2    
#> 19 Hpca     3    
#> 20 Gpr151   <NA>

